# ngBlur working properly only for tab out

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to call a method when an `input` field loses focus. I am using `ngBlur` for the same. It's working fine if we use tab button to remove focus from input field. But if I try to remove focus by clicking somewhere else in the form, then `ngBlur` does not work as I expect. Could you please let me know why this is happening? Is there any other way in angularJS to call a method after losing focus by clicking somewhere else using mouse?

I am using it as follows:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchParams.clientSearchValue"  
       ng-blur="getClientValidationErrors()" 
       ng-enter="validateAndSubmit()" 
       ng-disabled="!searchParams.clientSearchCode || searchParams.clientSearchCode == ''">
```

Comment: Always include the code that is causing you problems, without it we can only guess at what is happening

Answer (score 1):

ngBlur evaluate an expression on blur so u can set a variable in scope to true and watch the variable and fire than your function if the variable is true.

```
ng-blur="blur=true;focus=false;"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/deathhell/UTn5y/2/